# Is pointer arithmetic hard?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I remember when I first started learning C somebody told me that "pointer arithmetic is hard." I don't exactly understand what is hard about it though?

`arr[i]` == `*(arr + i)`
`*ptr = arr[2]` then `*ptr + 1 = arr[3]`

Is this really all there is to it, because neither of these concepts is as hard as I expected?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to use actual syntax instead of things like `[arr]i`.

Comment: I also might want to not be waking up and asking questions. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Most things in programming are hard the first time you try them. There's no way to answer your question objectively, though, so I am voting to close it as opinion-based.

Comment: It's not hard for a processor.  Half the machine code is about addresses, indexes and offsets.  Higher-level languages are good for avoiding the need to explictly having to deal with that stuff.

Comment: Seeing the number of errors you did in your question, I guess the answer is: yes, it is hard.

Comment: it's not hard as long as you are familiar with computer architecture. it is if not.

Comment: Let's not be too harsh (although it *is* opinion-based). It took me a while to "get" it; now I cannot *forget* it even if I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you mean `*(ptr + 1) = arr[3]` for that last one, then it seems like you have the hang of it. Making the substitution of the subscript operator (`[]`) for a pointer:

```
arr[3] === *(arr + 3)
```

Isn't very difficult. What gets tricky is when you have pointers point to the middle of an array, and then have to remember where they are in the array so you know what to index. So if `ptr1` points to the beginning of an array, and `ptr2` points at index 3, then  `*(ptr1 + 4)` and  `*(ptr2 + 1)` each yield the same value. In addition, if you have pointers in the middle of an array, you can subscript with negative numbers, something that isn't allowed in higher level languages like Java. So yes, it can get as complicated as one cares to make it.